# How to test code wrapped inside 3rd party component

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a component and some of its code e.g. some buttons is inside 3rd party tabs like that:

```
<vue-tabs>
  <v-tab :title="key">some code here</v-tab>
</vue-tabs>
```

How could I access that code inside those 3rd party tabs to test after mounting my component?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test this code in a context of this 3rd party tabs you should try to mount a parent component which wraps all of this code and try to find your code through wrapper.find('selector')

```js
wrapper.mount('WrapperComponent')
wrapper.find('your button selector').trigger('click') // for example
expect(wrapper.emitted('some click event')).toBe('some event argument')
```

*But I would recommend you to test your functional in another way, start to mount your Component which inside of your tabs out of context of this tabs, because this is **unit** test and it is much simpler to split your code into independent parts and test them one by one.*

```html
<vue-tabs>
  <v-tab :title="key">
    <WrapYourCodeComponent />
  </v-tab>
</vue-tabs>
```

vaue-tabs tabs and v-tab already have tested by its creators
but you need to test WrapYourCodeComponent

```js
mount(WrapYourCodeComponent)
...
```

Comment: find my selector doesn't work because for some reason I don't see any HTML that is inside vue-tabs. I'll probably split my code into smaller components.  it's just that amount of tabs depends on the button inside tab and there isn't much code aprt from that.

Comment: Did you add this 3d library on unit test? like Vue.use(library)

Comment: @AlexeyNazarov yes

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted my problem by importing vue tabs to the test file and adding it to the local vue instance.

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import VueTabs from 'vue-nav-tabs/dist/vue-tabs';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueTabs);

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(basicData, {
    localVue,
  });
});
```